# Confronting Numbers in Different Rows and Different Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

In summary, I want to analyze which numbers come together more frequently in lotto results.

***Table***: **list**

***Colums***: `number_1`,`number_2`,`number_3`,`number_4`,`number_5`,`number_6`

Data;

| number_1 | number_2 | number_3 | number_4 | number_5 | number_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | **30** | **40** | 50 |
| 14 | 20 | **30** | **40** | 51 | 52 |
| 12 | **57** | **28** | **36** | **55** | 65 |
| 13 | **28** | 35 | **36** | **57** | **55** |

**The result I should get with the query**

28,36,55,57 -> TARGET: 2

30,40 -> TARGET: 2

Answer (score 0):

Your aim seems to determine the numbers withdrawn more than once as far as I'm concerned. Then you can construct a dynamic SQL query of a DB dictionary table(namely `information_schema.columns`) including an unpivot through use of `UNION ALL` operator in order to combine all seperate columns into unique one, and then applying aggregation with `HAVING` clause such as

```sql
SET @sql = NULL;
       
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
       CONCAT( 
       'SELECT ',column_name,' AS number FROM ',table_name )
       SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
  INTO @sql     
  FROM information_schema.columns c
 WHERE table_name = 'list'
 ORDER BY ordinal_position;      

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT number, COUNT(*) AS target 
                     FROM (',@sql,') AS nr 
                    GROUP BY number 
                   HAVING COUNT(*)>1'); 

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=91a253eb2ec301454be0f09db8a554c0)</kbd>